# Debian 9 - Periodical high load by http and apt-config services

Tags: debian

I'm having a weird issue with my Debian 9 desktop KDE system (kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64).

I'm getting a 100% CPU spike for a few seconds that happens every 12 minutes. The screenshot below shows the processes which do this. They show for a couple seconds before they dissapear and after that I have two `apt-config` processes taking 5-14% for 8 minutes.

What could cause this? And how do I stop it from happening?

[image: Screenshot of processes]

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The service "Apper Monitor" is checking for updates over and over again. I disabled it from background services in Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Background Services.

Comment: What's "Apper" or "Apper Monitor"? A part of KDE, or something else? What package is it from, and what does it check for updates, apt's sources?

Comment: @Xen2050 it's included in the KDE desktop environment, It checks for apt updates and the description is "Watch transactions and Notify about Software Updates".

Comment: Ah, so a package updater, thanks. Sounds like a poorly chosen default setting (or maybe a bug) if it's trying every 12 minutes, sounds like it might even be re-downloading instead of just checking for changes first

Comment: Seems like a weird bug but so far only on this computer. I'm running same version of Debian/KDE on my laptop and have not gotten the same problem there.